# Cant get Junit to work with Spring in an ANT build

Tags: spring, ant, junit

I am trying to get Spring MVC and Junit working with eachother and I am having trouble configuring the build.xml file. I am fairly new at using ANT and do not really understand all the tutorials. I put the junit.jar file in the lib direcotory, but still am getting the following message from my console.

```
test:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Java\mmz\WEB-INF\build.xml:63: The <classpath> for <junit> must include junit.jar if not in Ant's own classpath

Total time: 223 milliseconds
```

**Edit**

Here is an example of wanting to run just one test

and I am not sure what I need to do, i tried doing something like the following, but I dont quite understand what its doing, so I dont know how to make changes

```
 <path id="classpath.test">
    <pathelement location="" />
    <pathelement location="${test.dir}" />
  </path>
<target name="test">
    <junit>
      <classpath refid="classpath.test" />
      <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
      <test name="TesterTest" />
    </junit>
</target>
```

I am pretty lost on what to do next. Thanks

Comment: Could you include the section of your build.xml that contains the junit task declaration?  Did you declare a `<classpath>` section in it?

Comment: I'm not sure where Spring comes into this, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copy-pasted your build.xml file then there is probably a classpath element somewhere. Probably near the top of the file. In that element they have probably listed some paths and/or files. You need to add the junit jar to this section.